# Why do some Lutheran churches have monasteries while others don't?

Tags: lutheranism, monasticism

Several Lutheran church bodies, including some of the Lutheran churches in Germany and Scandinavia, have active monastic communities. However, other Lutheran churches, including ELCA and LCMS in America, have none.

So, why do some Lutheran churches have monks while others don't? Is there a specific reason for this difference, or a rule prohibiting them in other Lutheran churches? If not, why don't those churches have monks?

Comment: I suspect the answer is a combination of "age" and "culture". As the birthplace of Lutheranism, German Evangelicals (note: European Lutherans don't necessarily call themselves "Lutheran") may be closer to "original" Lutheranism, which after all came out of Roman Catholicism, and therefore may be more "conservative". American Lutherans OTOH haven't been around as long and are likely more influenced by other Protestants that are even further from Catholicism.

Comment: It just seems like the decision to have or not have monks is arbitrary, and not based on any theological reasoning. Am I wrong?

Comment: I can't say for certain. I'm not *aware* of any theological reason, however. I wouldn't go so far as to call it "arbitrary", but as I suggested previously, the reasons may not be theological in origin. In any case, it's an interesting question, and I hope someone can give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to sort this question out, it's first of all important to learn what Luther (and thus, Lutherans) actually believe, teach, and confess.  One of the official documents of Lutherans is the Augsburg Confession. There is an entire article of faith on [Monastic Vows](https://bookofconcord.org/augsburg-confession/of-monastic-vows/). If you give it a read, you'll find that there are various reasons why the Lutheran Church (everywhere) has moved away from monasticism.

Why are there still some left over seminaries then?  That question is answered when we understand better the history of Europe, especially the [Prussian Union.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_Union_of_Churches). During that time the state took over the church, forcing various church bodies to worship together and change their doctrines so that they would not be offensive to the state government.  In that context, finding examples in Europe where the state still pays for and 'keeps up' monasteries (even though, long ago, Lutherans abandoned them for theological reasons) should not surprise us.  In Northern Europe, one *becomes* a Lutheran, not by being baptized, or by going through instruction. Instead, since Lutheranism is the state religion, everyone is *Lutheran*. And they become Lutheran by being born in that country.